# how to filter data from object mapper class

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, objectmapper

i want to implement search functionality in my app but i get data from services. i have an array like this in object mapper

```
class Country : Mappable {

var countryName:String = ""
var countryID:Int = 0
var countryImage:String = ""
var countryColor:String = ""

required init?(_ map: Map) {

}
func mapping(map: Map) {

    countryID           <- map["id"]
    countryName         <- map["name"]
    countryColor        <- map["color"]
    countryImage        <- map["image"]
}
}
```

from here i want to filter my data for search functionality how to do this.

here i am filtering only country names but i want to filter whole array how i can do that

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredData = self.countryNames.filter { (country:String) -> Bool in
        if country.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    print(filteredData)
    // update results table view

    self.resultController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to filter array of country - `[Country]` ?

Comment: yeah i want to filter whole array @NiravD

Comment: Then it is simply `let filter = countries.filter { $0.countryName.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) }`

Comment: but i also want to filter countryColor and countryImage

Comment: Then you can use `&&`/`||` with your multiple condition with `filter`.

Comment: What I mean to say is that I want to Filter my array on the basis of name. But get other values accordingly as well.

Comment: For that you need to create single array with objects of `Country` not multiple array that handle individual property of Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your array like this way.

```
let filter = countries.filter { $0.countryName.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchCon‌​troller.searchBar.te‌​xt!.lowercaseString) }
self.resultController.tableView.reloadData()
```